# Authorize a form request only if it an ajax call

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, laravel-request

I have a form that i want to authorize only if the call was made by ajax, so i tried

```
....
//MyRequest authorize function
public function authorize()
{
    return $this->ajax();
}
```

But after when i do the ajax call, in the console it shown `"This action is unauthorized."`, so how can i detect if the call was an ajax and return `true`, else return `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware).

```
php artisan make:middleware IsAjaxRequest
```

In app/Http/Middleware/IsAjaxRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

class IsAjaxRequest
{
    public function handle($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        // Check if the route is an ajax request only route
        if (!$request->ajax()) {
             abort(405, 'Unauthorized action.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to also register your middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php by adding the following in the $routeMiddleware array.

```
'ajax' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAjaxRequest::class
```

Then you can add it to any route handling an Ajax call

```
Route::get('users', 'UserController@method')->middleware('ajax');
```